# TomCat is taking 100% of CPU. is there a command I can put in to prevent it from doing that

Tags: java, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tuning Tomcat memory and cpu consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036707/tuning-tomcat-memory-and-cpu-consumption)

I've tried profilers but I can't find the source of the problem. is there a command or a way to basically limit how much CPU it can use?

**edit:**

no its not doing anything useful otherwise i wouldnt be asking.

**edit**

i'm using windows

Comment: Is it doing useful things while doing this (i.e. handling requests), or simply spinning in a noop?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi  its not the same question since im not trying to fine tune it nor is my application huge. im simply asking if there is a command like  xx-maxpermsize  but for CPU instead

Comment: in that case, check out @atamur's answer: the `nice` command would indeed do the job. Unless you're on a Windows platform, but that's not clear in your question.

Comment: On windows there are also options for modifying the process priority for the cpu scheduler. If you are willing to find something that does this in "javaland" then the answer is "no". There's nothing like -XX:maxCPU.

Comment: @atamur unless you're new to windows you'd know that cpu priority feature in windows does shit all

Answer (score 3):

depends on your host OS. In Linux you could try "nice"

Comment: @newuser9001 Yes, it's a real answer. "nice" is a command to make a process monopolize the CPU less (it's still going to do 100% when nothing else wants the CPU, though). While this isn't the solution you're looking for, it's semi-useful anyway.