# How does CoreOS allocates memory to a Docker container?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, memory-management, coreos

I'm running a container which includes a J2EE webapp with tomcat docker base image on CoreOS server instance in AWS (t2 medium). Recently I came across on how exceeding memory limits in Docker containers using Java inside would make the containers fail ([Resource](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/)). After reading the above article I was bit concerned on whether any of containers that I'm running on my CoreOS instance would face this issue in the future.

So I wanted to find out on what would be the default memory limit for a Docker container when no memory limit specified on docker run command, which is the way I'm running my docker containers. As discussed in this [forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/what-is-the-default-memory-limit-for-a-container/166) the answer stated its unlimited and its based on whatever the OS gives it.

**But** **I want to know how CoreOS decides the memory limit for a given container in detail and should I be worried on setting up a memory limit and CPU utilization of a container which is running a webapp with tomcat base image (Will there be any chance that a container exit due to memory overload issue in CoreOS?).**

None of the documents I came across on the internet provided a clear answer related to CoreOS or tomcat docker image, for this issue.

Note - I'm managing my Docker containers via systemd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Docker, by default, [a container has no resource constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/).  If you do not specify a memory limit for your container, [the limit is `unlimited`](https://forums.docker.com/t/what-is-the-default-memory-limit-for-a-container/166). However, it is possible that the memory is limited by your `cgroup` configuration. In addition, if you are using Kubernetes or another management system, it is possible to [define a default limit for a domain or namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/memory-default-namespace/).

Tomcat is a Java Application Server that runs on a virtual machine. The JVM tries to reserve an amount of memory depending on parameters such as the [`-Xms` and `-Xmx` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493913/how-to-set-the-maximum-memory-usage-for-jvm). In TOMCAT, these parameters may be specified in the `catalina.sh` startup script or the `CATALINA_OPTS` and `JAVA_OPTS` environment variables. If you do not specify a memory limit, [Java will use a default one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined) based on the version of the JVM and the available memory. There is a discussion on [Java 8 default limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272923/default-xmxsize-in-java-8). Java will not use more memory than the specified. If you call other non-Java programs from Tomcat, you must track the memory used by these applications.

- The [Tomcat in the Docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/tomcat/) does not define a memory limit for the Java runtime. The [default tomcat `catalina.sh`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/bin/catalina.sh) does not define a limit neither.
- If you use that template, Java (and Tomcat) will use the default values. You may check the values in your system using:

  ```
  java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
  ```

  In the page you mentioned, they use a CMD in the dockerfile:

  ```
  CMD java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintGCDetails $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar java-container.jar
  ```
- The page you mentioned used a [Fabric8 dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/fabric8/java-jboss-openjdk8-jdk/) that uses an [script](https://github.com/fabric8io-images/java/blob/master/images/jboss/openjdk8/jdk/container-limits) to calculate the container restrictions and use the 50% of the available memory as an upper boundary.
- Determining the amount of memory your application requires is part of the [Tomcat tunning](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-performance). You may find many [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036707/tuning-tomcat-memory-and-cpu-consumption) discussing this and another Tomcat parameters such as the number of allowed connections and of threads used in the connectors among others.
- You may define the memory limit using the `-e` switch to set environment variables.

  ```
  $ docker run -d --name mycontainer -p 8080:8080 -m 800M -e JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xmx300m' ...
  ```
- If you define a memory limit for your container, it must be greater than the used by Java. There is an [old discussion](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/57) in the Github issues with some ideas about how much memory to add.

---

Note that, recent Java versions considers the available memory and CPUs [according to the docker/cgroup defined limits](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits). Java systems (including tomcat) [may fail at startup](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/) if you do not have enough memory or the memory limit is less than the required by the runtime. Linux and Java uses an optimistic `malloc`and they may fail after a while. You must [check all of the cgroups, docker and JVM configurations](http://matthewkwilliams.com/index.php/2016/03/17/docker-cgroups-memory-constraints-and-java-cautionary-tale/).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Just what I was looking for. Thanks for all the resources as well.